# ASP.NET Forms Authentication .NET 4 - Document Name missing from ReturnURL in the querystring

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, returnurl

We have recently upgraded a web app from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4

This has introduced an issue with the ReturnURL in the querystring when logging in.

Prior to upgrade you could visit http://www.somedomain.com/myweb and on redirection to the login page the address would be this - http://www.somedomain.com/myweb/authenticate.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fmyweb%2fdefault.aspx

Now after upgrade the address is as above but default.aspx is missing from the ReturnURL parameter.

After logging in you are redirected to a blank page.

The default document in IIS is set as before.

Does anybody have any idea whats causing the document name to be stripped from ReturnURL after upgrade?

Comment: sounds like the URL is built via code, and there's something missing in the build statement/the URL object used may have changed and you may now have to specify a property to copy the querystring with it...

Comment: Why is /myweb/ returning a blank page? What blank page is it displaying?

Comment: Its not any specific page in the app.  Looking at the source this is all thats there...

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

As far as i can see the issue is that default.aspx is missing from the ReturnURL param.  It was all fine before the upgrade.

Comment: MaxOvrdrv - i will look into that

Comment: MaxOvrdrv

I've had a search of the code and we dont build up the URL dynamically.  I think this must be happening at the framework level as its only been an issue since changing .net version

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by placing the following code in Global.Application_BeginRequest

If HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath = "~/" Then
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx")
End If